# Issues of lifnei iver with non-Jews

Tags: halacha, gentiles, noachide-laws, lifnei-iver

Is the prohibition against lifnei iver--causing someone to sin--applicable if one causes a non-Jew to violate the [Noachide Laws](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/The_Seven_Noahide_Laws.html)? For example, suppose I (ch"v) give a Noachide something to eat that was taken from a living animal, and tell him it was not. If he eats it, am I guilty of an aveira? (...If not?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Bavli AZ 6b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=6b&format=pdf)

> מנין שלא יושיט אדם כוס של יין לנזיר ואבר מן החי לבני נח ת"ל ולפני עור לא תתן מכשול
>   Whence [do we know that] a man shouldn't pass a cup of wine to a Nazir nor a limb-from-a-live-animal to a gentile? The verse states: And before a blind person do not place a stumbling block.

Comment: And [Bavli BM 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.90b?lang=bi): "אמר רב פפא בני מערבא סברי לה כר' חידקא דאמר בני נח מצווין על הסירוס וקא עברי משום (ויקרא יט, יד) ולפני עור לא תתן מכשול". [Ohr Zarua](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Moses_of_Vienna) generalizes: "כל מצוה שאין הגוי מוזהר עליה מותר לו לישראל לומר לגוי לעשותה אבל מצוה שהגוי מוזהר עליה אסור לו לישראל לומר לגוי לעשותה משום לפני עור לא תתן מכשול".

Answer (score 6):

All [rishonim](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3718) agree that if it is real aver min hachai (it is included in the Torah prohibition) than it is absolutely forbidden to give to a non-Jew.

If it is only a rabbinical prohibition, there is a major dispute in the rishonim and [poskim](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1428). See רשב״א חולין נז ע״א ד״ה ה״ג, ר״ן שם, ועי׳ ש״ך סי׳ נה ס״ק יא, who permit when it's only a rabbinical prohibition. But see ס׳ התרומה סי׳ כג, סמ״ק סי׳ רא, יש״ש חולין פ״ד סי׳ יז, ועי׳ ש״ך שם ופליתי שם, וכ״מ ברש״י חולין קכט ע״ב ד״ה נשחטה, who say that since the rabbis made it like a Torah prohibition it is still forbidden to give to a non-Jew.